# How to create dataset based on specific condition of date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset in the below manner

```
year mon date      org
---- --- --------- ---
2018 mar 21-Mar-18 bb2
2018 mar 19-Mar-18 bbd
2018 feb 17-Feb-18 bbc
2018 feb 15-Feb-18 bba
2018 jan 15-Jan-18 abb
2018 jan 13-Jan-18 abc
```

and I am trying to get the data repeated in the following manner:

```
year mon date      org
---- --- --------- ---
2018 mar 21-Mar-18 bb2
2018 mar 19-Mar-18 bbd
2018 mar 17-Feb-18 bbc
2018 mar 15-Feb-18 bba
2018 mar 15-Jan-18 abb
2018 mar 13-Jan-18 abc
2018 feb 17-Feb-18 bbc
2018 feb 15-Feb-18 bba
2018 feb 15-Jan-18 abb
2018 feb 13-Jan-18 abc
2018 jan 15-Jan-18 abb
2018 jan 13-Jan-18 abc
```

***Edit:***
Sorry about the vague information.
This is a unique requirement, which states as:
" If a user queries for a month, the output should return all the rows of the selected month and the months before it."

So if you look at my existing dataset (this is just dummy data), if I filter for mar I should get 6 rows, for feb 4 rows and  2 rows for jan and so on in a backward manner. So the overall data will consist of 12 rows in a table.

I am working on oracle version 11.2.0.3

any idea or inputs is highly appreciated.

***EDIT 2:***
Sorry House, I was away for so long. The requirement was scraped so we didn't pursue this route. 
However if someone is looking to go in this route, the solution is

self join the table on "org" and Tab_A.column X is >= Tab_B.column X

given that X is a new column( based on year and mon, eg:201803)

Comment: Looks like homework to me. Just use a select query.

Comment: @Boneist, if there is a row for 31st jan, it would be All the records and or 31st jan added to the existing dataset.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I see this is your first post. You'll get better responses if you follow some guidelines: (1) don't just state the problem, show what you've tried and why it doesn't work (2) be more specific -- include the DDL of your table and talk about which tools you use (3) when I read your question, I have a hard time interpreting what you expect; it sounds like you have an algorithm in your head that you want to express as SQL, but you haven't told us what that algorithm is with enough precision for us to do much but guess based on your limited example.  Please refine, and Good Luck!

Comment: Please explain why you don't want year/mon to match the date.  That seems quite awkward.

Comment: I think I understand the requirement, but I am not sure it makes sense. Specifically, why is the month of interest equal to the max month (year/month) from the table? What if the dataset should be created through April or May 2018, but it just happens that the max date in the table is for March? Shouldn't the "report date" be an input variable instead?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - imagine that the business meaning is "monthly payments", always on the same date of the month, and the input table shows just the date of the first payment. The output dataset must show a row for each monthly payment. That makes sense to me (except for the question I just asked in another comment).

Comment: A couple more questions: Is ORG the primary key in the input table? (meaning never NULL and no duplicates). Also, what is your Oracle version? As reported when you run `select * from v$version`. Include that with all your questions!

Comment: @mathguy, I have updated the actual requirement statement and the version details.

Comment: How does a user query for a month? Does she select a year and a month, from two different drop-down lists? Or in what other way?

Comment: @mathguy, users have access to db tables but are not adept in using multiple reference tables. So the idea is to have the data into a table so that users can query with a simple select and filter condition ( probably on month and year)

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest date for each month/year in the table, you may use `max` with a `group by` as follows (table name wasn't given, let's call it `myTable`):

```
SELECT year, mon, max(date) FROM myTable GROUP BY year, mon
```

Then getting your repeated data can be done with a join:

```
SELECT m2.year, m2.mon, m.date, m.org
FROM myTable AS m
    INNER JOIN (SELECT year, mon, max(date) AS maxDate FROM myTable GROUP BY year, mon) AS m2
        ON m.date <= m2.maxDate
ORDER BY m2.maxDate DESC, m.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting rows if a user passes in a month and year, this should do the trick:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 2018 YEAR, 'mar' mon, to_date('21/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'bb2' org FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2018 YEAR, 'mar' mon, to_date('19/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'bbd' org FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2018 YEAR, 'feb' mon, to_date('17/02/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'bbc' org FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2018 YEAR, 'feb' mon, to_date('15/02/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'bba' org FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2018 YEAR, 'jan' mon, to_date('15/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'abb' org FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2018 YEAR, 'jan' mon, to_date('13/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'abc' org FROM dual)
-- end of sample data setup
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  to_date(mon||'/'||YEAR, 'mon/yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') <= to_date(:dt, 'mon/yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english');
```

:dt = apr/2018

```
      YEAR MON DT          ORG
---------- --- ----------- ---
      2018 mar 21/03/2018  bb2
      2018 mar 19/03/2018  bbd
      2018 feb 17/02/2018  bbc
      2018 feb 15/02/2018  bba
      2018 jan 15/01/2018  abb
      2018 jan 13/01/2018  abc
```

:dt = mar/2018

```
      YEAR MON DT          ORG
---------- --- ----------- ---
      2018 mar 21/03/2018  bb2
      2018 mar 19/03/2018  bbd
      2018 feb 17/02/2018  bbc
      2018 feb 15/02/2018  bba
      2018 jan 15/01/2018  abb
      2018 jan 13/01/2018  abc
```

:dt = feb/2018

```
      YEAR MON DT          ORG
---------- --- ----------- ---
      2018 feb 17/02/2018  bbc
      2018 feb 15/02/2018  bba
      2018 jan 15/01/2018  abb
      2018 jan 13/01/2018  abc
```

:dt = jan/2018

```
      YEAR MON DT          ORG
---------- --- ----------- ---
      2018 jan 15/01/2018  abb
      2018 jan 13/01/2018  abc
```

:dt = dec/2017

```
no rows selected
```

You would need to amend the input accordingly; in my query, I've assumed the month being queried for would be in `mon/yyyy` format; that may or may not be the case.

Also, since we're using `mon`, I've added in third optional parameter to ensure we're querying with the right date language. The query wouldn't work if the client's language was french, but the data's language is english!

Lastly, this seems like a bad design. You could easily change this table to have just the dt column, and add virtual columns to the table to create the month and year columns (although I wouldn't separate those out; I'd simply do `trunc(dt, 'mm')` and leave it as an extra date column. Far more flexible, IMO) and index the virtual column(s) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for trying boneist. The problem is not with fetching based on months but
i need to in a way duplicate them, data from selected month and all older months.
In order to achieve that select criteria i need the data to be in place in a repeated manner

Comment: You need this for a single month or for all months? Seems like an odd requirement; what happens when you’re 10 years down the line? That seems like a lot of data to be returned!